# How to upload image to Cloudinary and save the image url to mongodb. using next js 13.4+ in app router

Tags: mongodb, next.js, next.js13, multer, cloudinary

I have a page where I have a file input field. User will select a image from device and press upload button. After clicking upload button, image will be uploaded to Cloudinary and image url will be saved to mongodb table. I want to do this in Next.js 13.4 using app router. But cannot find suitable guide. Anyone please help.

I tried using available resources i find online but no tutorial based on Next.js 13.4+ version.

Comment: You should save the filename in database. and whenever you want to load that image, you put the filename inside the URL and the path of the file: `https://cdn.com/path/to/{FILENAME}` you can make this URL on backend and send it to client

Comment: This cannot be done because the submitting filename and the Cloudinary generated filename aren't similar.

Comment: I don't have any experience with Cloudinary (I worked only with S3) but you should have access to the generated filename somehow

Answer (score 0):

Cloudinary has a tutorial on how to upload assets specifically for NextJS.  The tutorial covers how to integrate the upload widget, upload preset creation, and customization of the widget.

https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_assets_in_nextjs_tutorial

Comment: I know how to upload image to Cloudinary but i want to know how i can save the uploaded image url in my mongodb database.